# Is there an example for getting Proguard working with Cocos2d-x? And twitter4j

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, proguard

I've searched discuss.cocos for an example but there isn't one. Feeling this to be a more OS agnostic platform to ask on I search for enlightenment here.

I got a massive headache after turning it on by writing

> proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt

in project.properties in my project's base directory.

[image]

I couldn't copy-past text because the console display in Eclipse immediately cleared and presented like there was nothing wrong but I got "error code 1. See console" type of message, repeatedly.

Though the problem appears to be with twitter4j I'm sure there are many more warnings that scrolled by before that, well, I'm not sure, the whole thing was so sudden.

I've trawled this site for help and while most advice consists of adding `dontwarn` lines I feel I need to be exporting libraries instead of, as I did with twitter4j, just copying the libjar to my project's own lib folder.

I've tried adding:

```
-dontwarn twitter4j.management.**
-dontwarn twitter4j.**
-dontwarn javax.management.**
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.**
-keep class javax.**  { *; }
-keep class org.**  { *; }
-keep class twitter4j.**  { *; }
-keep class java.lang.management.**  { *; }
-keep class com.google.code.**  { *; }
-keep class oauth.signpost.**  { *; }

-libraryjars /libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar

-keep class twitter4j.**
-keepclassmembers class twitter4j.** {
    <init>(...);
    <methods>;
    <fields>;
}
```

To proguard-project.txt but it had no effect. I'm tending not to want to bother with proguard since C++ is much better for obfuscation anyway. It's strange how none of the howto's I read promoted including the entire twitter4j project. I prefer the small 300kb library. But not if it's limiting optimisations in other respects.

My SDK is version 22.6 by the way.

____EDIT____

In looking for a complete example i found SDK/tools/proguard/examples/android.pro

I tried copy pasting the lot to no further effect but was disconcerted by the advice in the header of that file:

## If you're using the Android SDK (version 2.3 or higher), the android tool

## already creates a file like this in your project, called proguard.cfg.

## It should contain the settings of this file, minus the input and output paths

## (-injars, -outjars, -libraryjars, -printmapping, and -printseeds).

## The generated Ant build file automatically sets these paths.

Android tool? proguard.cfg? Surely proguard knows the new files are merely instructed to reference the configs in the SDK/tools/proguard directory?

proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt

Answer (score 0):

You say you're changing proguard-project.txt, but are you actually using that file? Have you changed project.properties to point to your file instead of the default android one?

```
proguard.config=proguard-project.txt
```

Comment: My first step, adding `proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt` caused proguard to be invoked and complain. I've updated my question to show the SDK I used. I believe your answer refers to an earlier version. But I will try it, tomorrow.

Comment: I'm getting more errors (376 unresolved references, vs 118 my way) doing it your way. That was it might have been done in like SDK < 20 or something.

Answer (score 0):

Your `project.properties` file should point to Android's default configuration and to your own project-specific configuration:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

This is the standard line in the properties files that the Android SDK generates.

In your `proguard-project.txt` file, you can then add `-keep` options to avoid problems with code that performs reflection. In this case, you should also add `-dontwarn` options to reassure ProGuard that the missing dependencies are not a problem in practice. It will then proceed processing the application.

You should not add `-libraryjars` options, since the Android build process already automatically specifies all necessary `-injars`, `-outjars`, and `-libraryjars` for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go, if I haven't already, personally I'm minded to drop twitter4j.